# Copy to clipboard from tableview

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview

I have Written a code and I need to copy the selected rows in Qt C++

My `OTPWindow.cpp`  file has 
this function

```
SafeOTPWindow::on_tblCopy_clicked()
{
    QClipboard* clip = qApp->clipboard();
    clip->setText(ui->tblLog->text());
}
```

My `OTPWindow.h` file has

```
private slots:
     void on_tblCopy_clicked();
```

I am getting an error

text is not an member of `Qtableview`. How can I solve this error

I need to copy the text contents from `tableview` which are in rows inside What property should I set in .cpp file. Here `tblLog` is my `tableview`.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes this worked. I also tried out using another method that is using on Doubleclick it copys that also worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An way to achieve what you want is get the list of the selected items and concatenate the text of these item, like as below:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(ui->tableView->model());

if (!model) //Check if listview has a model
    return;

QModelIndexList indexlist = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();

QString str;

int lastrow = -1;

foreach (const QModelIndex &index, indexlist)
{
    if (lastrow >= 0)
    {
        if (index.row() == lastrow)
            str.append(Qt::Key_Space); //Add space between items in same line
        else
            str.append("\n"); //Add break line if entering in a new line
    }

    str.append(model->index(index.row(), index.column()).data().toString());

    lastrow = index.row();
}

str.append("\n"); //Add break line to the end of the string

QClipboard* clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
clipboard->setText(str); //Copy the string to clipboard
```